# Advice on Modal BootStrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with boostrap latest version finally getting the hang of it and try to add another modal combined with the one i already have. Well no luck and got stuck. is there a way to add another modal that works together with the previous modal?

the reason why i wanted to try to get another modal in there to show off the twitch emotes plus commands they can use to make it easier for the user.

in other words another box on the right side (where its marked with a red box)

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJduj.png

Comment: What do you mean by "works together with the previous modal"? Are you simply asking if you can have multiple modals on a page or something else? And you should post the related code (HTML/CSS/JS) that is related to your question.

Comment: what i mean by it is using one button to open 2 modals ( one is the video feed and the second just text )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with setting a `data-target` for the same `class` instead of using `href` with an `ID`. You'll have to adjust the position of them depending on where you want to two and how big they are etc.

Open up the example to **full-page** and you'll see.

```
data-target=".myModals"
```

```css
#myModal2 {
  top: 40%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModals" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch Modals</a>

<div class="modal fade myModals" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade myModals" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: VanBurenX thanks for the advice on this is exactly what i was looking for and never thought about using the class for this i always tried it with the id tag.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can open a modal via JavaScript. Since you already have jQuery loaded, try something like this.

Assuming you have a modals with IDs of videoFeed and textFeed.

```
$( "#" ).bind( "click", function() {
    $('#videoFeed').modal('toggle');
    $('#textFeed').modal('toggle');
});
```